# How to start a validator in solana?

Tags: validator, devnet, testnet, node

I have tried starting a local validator using solana cli command solana-test-validator. It works fine and starts from block 1 for localhost. But when I am following this doc: [Starting a Validator](https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start) and connecting to devnet/testnet validator, the log file shows the following errors

- Received no response at tcp/8899, check your port configuration:
  timed out waiting on channel
- Received no response at tcp/8900, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on channel
- Received no response at tcp/9000, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on channel

As I have understood from the log file, this might have something to do with ports but i am not sure what exactly as all the incoming connections to all ports are open. So can anyone suggest a solution?

Edit: I need it running on devnet for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux/mac machine -> use this command to see if your port is already in use by any other process:

```
lsof -nPi | grep <PORTNUM>
```

you can then kill the process that is using the port, or change the port that it uses and restart it!

NOTE: check if your host meets the devnet validator hardware requirements

Hope this helps!

Comment: No other process is using that port. I checked the processes after starting the validator and can confirm only solana validator is using those ports.